# When should we recommend to delete an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

We have a couple of mediocre answers in the review queue. They are more appropriate as comments.

Right now, I just skip them in the queue and I ask the users to clarify their answers.

**When is it appropriate to delete answers?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right [from the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers):

> Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be
>   removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

Comment: Keep in mind that you can flag to convert something to a comment (although whether that works is dependent on having moderators).

Comment: ah thanks ! Yes, changing from answer to a comment is probably the solution. Too bad that we still don't have moderators.

Comment: Generally, moderators **should be wary of converting to comment** if the answer poster doesn't have the ability to comment on the post to which the answer should be converted to a comment to. (Phew!)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Comment comment answer comment answer something something yes I agree. :P